# Application switches protocol from https:// (secured) to http:// (non secured) when user signs out of the Application

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am able to Log into my Application using secured URL (https://) but Application switches protocol from https:// (secured) to http:// (non secured) when user signs out of the Application. I want a secured prortocol (https://) even after signing out.
Can anyone please help. I am using below JS code.

```
function logout(smsUserID, platform, languageid, scenario, invokeType, pageid, fromLoginPage, rumbaLogin) {
  //get sessionID
  var sessionID = $('#sessionID').val();
  //Create the logout URL
  var logoutURL = "/ebook/ebookLogout.do?";

  //Check for scenario
  if (scenario != undefined && scenario != '') {
    logoutURL += "scenario=" + scenario;
  }
  if (fromLoginPage != undefined && fromLoginPage != '') {
    logoutURL += "&fromloginpage=" + fromLoginPage;
  }
  //Check for sessionID
  if (sessionID != undefined && sessionID != '') {
    logoutURL += "&sessionID=" + sessionID;
  }

  //Check for scenario
  if (invokeType != undefined && invokeType != '') {
    logoutURL += "&invokeType=" + invokeType;
  }

  if (rumbaLogin != undefined && rumbaLogin != '') {
    logoutURL += "&rumbaLogin=" + rumbaLogin;
  }
  //Check for platform
  if (platform != undefined && platform != '') {
    logoutURL += "&platform=" + platform;
  }
  //Check for langauge id
  if (languageid != undefined && languageid != '') {
    logoutURL += "&languageid=" + languageid;
  }


  //Check for user ID
  if (smsUserID != undefined && smsUserID != '') {
    logoutURL += "&smsUserID=" + smsUserID;
  }

  //Set logut URL
  document.bookShelfForm.action = logoutURL;
  //submit the logout URL       
  document.bookShelfForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: Might not be that code that's the culprit. What does `ebookLogout.do` do? Does it send a redirect, or does is display a page? If redirect, then it's probably in the redirect that the `https` is dropped.

Comment: @Andreas : Yes , it's redirecting.

Comment: Depending on which browser you use, you can see what's going on. E.g. in FireFox, press F12 and select the "Network" tab, then run your code (click "Logout" I presume), and see the HTTP being sent (from `submit()` call) and received (redirect from server).

Comment: you can user <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> tag in the web.xml. the app server will automatically redirects the requests to the SSL port even if you try to use HTTP.